# XML Validation error: No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: xml

First few lines from XSD

```
`<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.06" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.06">
        <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"> 
        </xs:element>
        <xs:complexType name="AccountIdentification4Choice">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">AccountIdentification4Choice</xs:documentation>
                <xs:documentation source="Definition" xml:lang="EN">Specifies the unique identification of an account as assigned by the account servicer.</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="IBAN" type="IBAN2007Identifier">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">IBAN</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation source="Definition" xml:lang="EN">International Bank Account Number (IBAN) - identifier used internationally by financial institutions to uniquely identify the account of a customer. Further specifications of the format and content of the IBAN can be found in the standard ISO 13616 "Banking and related financial services - International Bank Account Number (IBAN)" version 1997-10-01, or later revisions.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Othr" type="GenericAccountIdentification1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">Other</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation source="Definition" xml:lang="EN">Unique identification of an account, as assigned by the account servicer, using an identification scheme.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>`
```

When I validate my XML file with this, I get the error mentioned in the subject. Not sure what is the problem. I think it is very basic, but not sure what it is.

First few lines from XML

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.054.001.02 camt.054.001.02.xsd">
  <BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>00ZW0YFOV2H1KKWA0003FLAALFALFV5328U</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2017-12-06T21:56:02</CreDtTm>
      <MsgRcpt>
        <Id>
          <OrgId>
            <Othr>
              <Id>F704863Z</Id>
              <Issr>EBICS</Issr>
            </Othr>
          </OrgId>
        </Id>
      </MsgRcpt>
      <MsgPgntn>
        <PgNb>1</PgNb>
        <LastPgInd>true</LastPgInd>
      </MsgPgntn>
    </GrpHdr>
    <Ntfctn>
      <Id>00ZW0YFOV2H1KKWA0003FLAALFALFV5328U</Id>
      <CreDtTm>2017-12-06T21:53:28</CreDtTm>
      <Acct>`
```

Comment: Can you post the xml ?

Comment: Added the XML now

Comment: How is the declaration of the type `Document` in the XSD?
The error message seems to just report that your XML doesn't conform to the given schema. Besides, it would be helpful if can post the complete xsd.

Comment: I thought of posting it completely, but the complete xsd is of 6947 rows and thought its too lengthy to post.

Comment: you could use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) for example to upload big or huge files. But trying to isolate the problem by yourself will certainly lead you to learn more and others to help you.
See also [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)